# Restrict functor parameter type and constness

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, functor

I am trying to implement a resource protection class which would combine data along with a shared mutex (actually, QReadWriteLock, but it's similar). The class must provide the method to apply a user-defined function to the data when the lock is acquired. I would like this apply method to work differently depending on the function parameter (reference, const reference, or value). For example, when the user passes a function like `int (const DataType &)` it shouldn't block exclusively as we are just reading the data and, conversely, when the function has the signature like `void (DataType &)` that implies data modification, hence the exclusive lock is needed.

My first attempt was to use std::function:

```cpp
template <typename T>
class Resource1
{
public:
    template <typename Result>
    Result apply(std::function<Result(T &)> &&f)
    {
        QWriteLocker locker(&this->lock);   // acquire exclusive lock
        return std::forward<std::function<Result(T &)>>(f)(this->data);
    }

    template <typename Result>
    Result apply(std::function<Result(const T &)> &&f) const
    {
        QReadLocker locker(&this->lock);    // acquire shared lock
        return std::forward<std::function<Result (const T &)>>(f)(this->data);
    }

private:
    T data;
    mutable QReadWriteLock lock;
};
```

But std::function doesn't seem to restrict parameter constness, so `std::function<void (int &)>` can easily accept `void (const int &)`, which is not what I want. Also in this case it can't deduce lambda's result type, so I have to specify it manually:

```cpp
Resource1<QList<int>> resource1;
resource1.apply<void>([](QList<int> &lst) { lst.append(11); });     // calls non-const version (ok)
resource1.apply<int>([](const QList<int> &lst) -> int { return lst.size(); });  // also calls non-const version (wrong)
```

My second attempt was to use `std::result_of` and return type SFINAE:

```cpp
template <typename T>
class Resource2
{
public:
    template <typename F>
    typename std::result_of<F (T &)>::type apply(F &&f)
    {
        QWriteLocker locker(&this->lock);   // lock exclusively
        return std::forward<F>(f)(this->data);
    }

    template <typename F>
    typename std::result_of<F (const T &)>::type apply(F &&f) const
    {
        QReadLocker locker(&this->lock);    // lock non-exclusively
        return std::forward<F>(f)(this->data);
    }

private:
    T data;
    mutable QReadWriteLock lock;
};

Resource2<QList<int>> resource2;
resource2.apply([](QList<int> &lst) {lst.append(12); });    // calls non-const version (ok)
resource2.apply([](const QList<int> &lst) { return lst.size(); });  // also calls non-const version (wrong)
```

Mainly the same thing happens: as long as the object is non-const the mutable version of apply gets called and result_of doesn't restrict anything.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may do the following

```
template <std::size_t N>
struct overload_priority : overload_priority<N - 1> {};

template <> struct overload_priority<0> {};

using low_priority = overload_priority<0>;
using high_priority = overload_priority<1>;

template <typename T>
class Resource
{
public:
    template <typename F>
    auto apply(F&& f) const
    // -> decltype(apply_impl(std::forward<F>(f), high_priority{}))
    {
        return apply_impl(std::forward<F>(f), high_priority{});
    }

    template <typename F>
    auto apply(F&& f)
    // -> decltype(apply_impl(std::forward<F>(f), high_priority{}))
    {
        return apply_impl(std::forward<F>(f), high_priority{});
    }

private:
    template <typename F>
    auto apply_impl(F&& f, low_priority) -> decltype(f(std::declval<T&>()))
    {
        std::cout << "ReadLock\n";
        return std::forward<F>(f)(this->data);
    }

    template <typename F>
    auto apply_impl(F&& f, high_priority) -> decltype(f(std::declval<const T&>())) const
    {
        std::cout << "WriteLock\n";
        return std::forward<F>(f)(this->data);
    }

private:
    T data;
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/84421aea51d77fd1)

Comment: Well done! The only thing I don't understand is why to use template overload_priority structures instead of just:

    struct low_priority {};
    struct high_priority : low_priority {};

Comment: I am also curious to know your opinion about such design. Shared data protection is a pretty common task, but I don't find much information on how to encapsulate this functionality. Any references, examples, guidelines would be appreciated.

Comment: For the priority, it is mostly a pattern that allows more levels, but indeed, the simpler inheritance is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Jarod has given a workaround, but I'll explain why you cannot achieve that this regular way.
The problem is that:

1. Overload resolution prefers non-const member functions over const member functions when called from a non-const object
2. whatever object this signature `void foo(A&)` can accept, `void foo(const A&)` can also the same object. The latter even has a broader binding set than the former.

Hence, to solve it, you will have to at least defeat point 1 before getting to 2. As Jarod has done.

From your signatures (see my comment annotations):

```
template <typename F>
typename std::result_of<F (T &)>::type apply(F &&f)              //non-const member function
{
    return std::forward<F>(f)(this->data);
}

template <typename F>
typename std::result_of<F (const T &)>::type apply(F &&f) const //const member function
{
    return std::forward<F>(f)(this->data);
}
```

When you call it like:

```
resource2.apply([](QList<int> &lst) {lst.append(12); });   //1
resource2.apply([](const QList<int> &lst) { return lst.size(); });   //2
```

First of all, remember that `resource2` isn't a `const` reference. Hence, the `non-const` membr function of apply will always be prefered by Overload resolution.

Now, taking the case of the first call `//1`, Whatever that lambda is callable with, then then the second one is also callable with that object

A simplified mock-up of what you are trying to do is:

```
struct A{
    template<typename Func>
    void foo(Func&& f); //enable if we can call f(B&);

    template<typename Func>
    void foo(Func&& f) const; //enable if we can call f(const B&);
};

void bar1(B&);
void bar2(const B&);

int main(){
    A a;
    a.foo(bar1);
    a.foo(bar2);

    //bar1 and bar2 can be both called with lvalues
    B b;
    bar1(b);
    bar2(b);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you want to discriminate a parameter that's  a `std::function` that takes a `const` reference versus a non-constant reference.

The following SFINAE-based approach seems to work, using a helper specialization class:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

template<typename ...Args>
using void_t=void;

template<typename Result,
     typename T,
     typename lambda,
     typename void_t=void> class apply_helper;

template <typename T>
class Resource1
{
public:

    template <typename Result, typename lambda>
    Result apply(lambda &&l)
    {
        return apply_helper<Result, T, lambda>::helper(std::forward<lambda>(l));
    }
};

template<typename Result, typename T, typename lambda, typename void_t>
class apply_helper {

 public:

    static Result helper(lambda &&l)
    {
        std::cout << "T &" << std::endl;

        T t;
        return l(t);
    }
};


template<typename Result, typename T, typename lambda>
class apply_helper<Result, T, lambda,
           void_t<decltype( std::declval<lambda>()( std::declval<T>()))>> {
 public:

    static Result helper(lambda &&l)
    {
        std::cout << "const T &" << std::endl;
        return l( T());
    }
};


Resource1<int> test;

int main()
{
    auto lambda1=std::function<char (const int &)>([](const int &i)
                               {
                                   return (char)i;
                               });
    auto lambda2=std::function<char (int &)>([](int &i)
                               {
                                   return (char)i;
                               });

    auto lambda3=[](const int &i) { return (char)i; };
    auto lambda4=[](int &i) { return (char)i; };

    test.apply<char>(lambda1);
    test.apply<char>(lambda2);
    test.apply<char>(lambda3);
    test.apply<char>(lambda4);
}
```

Output:

```
const T &
T &
const T &
T &
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e2f684d3d1046c17)

The `helper()` static class in the specialized class can now be modified to take a `this` parameter, instead, and then use it to trampoline back into the original template's class's method.

Comment: Compile with gcc, but not with clang: [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8a35d6647b40cf7e)

Comment: I am not familiar with clang's diagnostics, but it looks to me like clang had no problems with substituting either specialization. I don't see how that's possible, to be able to substitute both `const std::function<Result(const T &)> *` and `const std::function<Result(T &)> *` when `T` is not const-qualified.

Comment: That seems strange too. But anyway, your code doesn't work with regular lambda [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b88726421cf39206)

Comment: True, but only a little bit more work is needed to make it work. Updated.

Comment: [Note]: As OP mentions c++11 and may so have outdated compiler, [`void_t`](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%2b%2b/1169/sfinae-substitution-failure-is-not-an-error/3778/void-t#t=201609191700403785232) may require a different implementation.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the capture lists of your lambdas are empty, you can rely on the fact that such a lambda decays to a function pointer.
It's suffice to discriminate between the two types.

It follows a minimal, working example:

```
#include<iostream>

template <typename T>
class Resource {
public:
    template <typename Result>
    Result apply(Result(*f)(T &)) {
        std::cout << "non-const" << std::endl;
        return f(this->data);
    }

    template <typename Result>
    Result apply(Result(*f)(const T &)) const {
        std::cout << "const" << std::endl;
        return f(this->data);
    }

private:
    T data;
};

int main() {
    Resource<int> resource;
    resource.apply<void>([](int &lst) { });
    resource.apply<int>([](const int &lst) -> int { return 42; });
}
```